# Does a high autocorrelation imply high predictability using an AR model?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Assuming that I have a list of time-series which all have significant autocorrelation at lag 1 and no significant autocorrelation at any other lags. So if I want to test for the predictive abilities of my time-series, would the one with the highest autocorrelation at first lag also have the highest predictive ability? Assuming that I am using some statistical technique to measure predictive performance like RMSE or MAE.

Comment: First off, if the Auto-correlation cuts off at lag one drastically you probably want to use an MA(1) not an AR(1).  Besides that the answer to your question is no not necessarily, because the series with the higher auto-correlation may have a higher variance, and so RMSE may still be higher.